# How C printf function knows the integer size passed?

Tags: c, pointers, printf, variadic-functions

In the following sample code, how did printf knew the size that shall be printed for uint8_t while the mentioned format is only "0x%x" and passd type is uint32_t? how did printf know that in first call it must print 4 bytes and the second call it must only print 1 byte?

```
uint32_t X = 0xAABBCCDD;
printf("uint32_t 0x%x\n", (uint32_t) X);
printf("uint8_t  0x%x\n", (uint8_t) X);
```

Output

```
uint32_t 0xaabbccdd
uint8_t  0xdd
```

Comment: It just doesn't print leading zeros.

Comment: All values smaller than `int` are promoted and passed to `printf` (or any other variadic function) as `int`. This is why it works. Try it with larger types and you will run into problems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't know.  In both cases you're giving `printf` an `[unsigned] int`, due to the *default argument promotions*.  Your code is equivalent to this:<sup>1</sup>

```
printf("uint32_t 0x%x\n", (unsigned int)(uint32_t) X);
printf("uint8_t  0x%x\n", (int)(uint8_t) X);
```

The promotion rule is:

> **[6.3.1.1]** If an `int` can represent all values of the original type [...], the value is converted to an `int`; otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned int`.

The only rule that `printf` follows at this point is to not print leading zeros.

Note that mapping a signed `int` to `%x` is technically undefined behaviour.

---

<sup>1. I'm assuming you have 32-bit `int`s here.</sup>

Comment: `uint8_t` is default promoted to `int`, not `unsigned int`, because promotion is value preserving and the range of `uint8_t` always fits into `int` without needing to go to `unsigned int`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ...making it technically undefined behaviour , since `unsigned int` is expected but `int` received, although we usually don't worry about that

Answer (score 2):

In

```
printf("uint8_t  0x%x\n", (uint8_t) X);
```

`uint8_t` is definitely a lower-ranking type than `int`, and so `uint8_t` will be promoted to `int` and `"%x"` will work.

```
//potentially invokes UB depending on platform
printf("uint32_t  0x%x\n", (uint32_t) X);
```

is nonportable code. In theory, you don't know what real type `uint32_t` is and so you should be using the `PRIx32` macro from `inttypes.h`. For consistency/simplicity's sake, you can use `PRIx8` for `uint8_t` too.

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    uint32_t X = 0xAABBCCDD;
    printf("uint8_t  0x%" PRIx8 "\n", (uint8_t) X);
    printf("uint32_t 0x%" PRIx32 "\n", (uint32_t) X);
}
```